# Too many event listeners are slowing down click response

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have a form with hundreds of toggle buttons. I also have around one hundred event listeners that look like this:

```
function my_function() {
/*do a bunch of stuff*/
}
addEventListener("click", function() { my_function(); })
```

As the months go by developing my form, the delay becomes bigger and bigger after each click. I can understand why.

My question is, is there an easy fix to improve it? For example, if I target the element more specifically, like this:

```
addEventListener("click", function({target}) { 
    if(target.matches("input[type='radio']")) { my_function(); } 
});
```

Will that improve load time or will it just make my code longer? Or will using jquery to trigger the event somehow be faster?

Comment: Why do you have so many toggle buttons?

Comment: If the wait goes up *after every click* then something besides the initial quantity is at play. It's also not clear what you're adding the click listener *to*.

Comment: See _event delegation_: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events

Comment: What is `addEventListener`? Is that `window.addEventListener` or is it actually `element.addEventListener` but not showing use `element.`?

Comment: Yes, you may have recursion happening. Please provide more detail.

Comment: I have so many toggle buttons because it's just a really long form with many questions... each question comes with a yes/no toggle.

To answer Dave Newton and clarify the purpose: for example, when a user clicks on "yes" to the question "do you have children", it will trigger a new box that will ask "how many children"

Comment: You may want to consider a different, multipage design.

Comment: To answer Heretic Monkey, it's just addEventListener by itself. So I guess in your question, that's the second one: element.addEventListener

Comment: No, it's the first one. You may want to take a quick step back and get a handle on some JS/DOM/UX before going any further down this road--besides that the form is essentially unusable from a user perspective a deeper understanding of event handling would likely be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to build a wrapper and assign the event listener to that, then you can determine what has been clicked using characteristics of the specific element...

```
const my_function = event => {
  if (event.target.nodeName == "INPUT") {
    if (event.target.type == "radio") console.log('this is a radio button!')
  }
  if (event.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") {
    if (event.target.type == "submit") console.log('this is a regular button!')
  }
}

document.getElementById('wrapper').addEventListener("click", event => my_function(event))
```

And the HTML...

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="radio" id="test">Hello World</input>
  </br>
  <button type="radio" id="test">Hello World</button>
</div>
```

[Here's a working pen](https://codepen.io/paulmartin91/pen/abJLWEe?editors=1011)

You can also use id's if you want to distinguish between different elements of the same type. Use `event.target.innerHTML` if you want to take any information from the element itself.

EDIT: I've also added an obscene number of buttons/inputs to the codepen to show you this fixes your slowdown issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as well as everyone else's efforts. I have a lot to learn! That's why I'm here. Time to go through the docs :)

Answer (score -2):

Add one event listener to the parent object and check if the clicked target is a toggle button, i.e. by checking the class name:

```
parent.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('toggle-button')) {
        // do your stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score -4):

you need to remove eventListeners on complition

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: This isn't really an answer. It doesn't say how or when to do so. Also, link-only answers aren't considered valuable on SO.

Comment: On its own this advice doesn't make much sense--the OP *may* need to "remove event listeners", but there's no way of knowing at this point.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for telling me, I'm pretty new here as you can see

Comment: Also, you can't use `removeEventListener` with anonymous functions.